# What do the little blue squares on the minimap mean?

Tags: battlefield-3

On the minimap I occasionally see small blue squares with little lines coming out of the corners. What do they mean? My first guess was that they were nearby explosions, but I think I see them too often for that to be the case.

**EDIT**: [Here's a pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0E8iZ.png), you can see two in the lower left (they might be circles and not squares like I first thought).

[image: Here's a pic]

Comment: I found this video which goes over some of the minimap icons, but I didn't see one that was what you described.  Perhaps it will help in general anyhow: http://youtu.be/SE1fjtMayn4?t=3m8s

Comment: Thanks for the video! I used it to snag a screencap of what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Blue **`¤`** on mini-map means friendly anti-tank mine or friendly C4. You can also see these symbols over them when you're nearby. Even in HC mode.

Answer (score 2):

I think they are one of the following:

- capture points (the blue square), which your squad leader has designated you defend (the lines from the corners)
- mines: the antitank mines (and possibly claymores) are small squares (I seem to recall them being circles) with corner lines

a picture of it would help greatly, just to be sure, but I'm quite sure it's mines. will try to make my own screenshot later.

Comment: Ahh, you might be right with the second one. (I wasn't talking about the capture points, although that does fit the description. The ones I'm talking about are smaller.)

Comment: [Here's a pic of what I mean](http://i.imgur.com/KbNgu.png) (lower left)

Comment: Those are AT mines.  @Holger's answer is correct